# Choose from tensor array of arrays using array of indices

Tags: python, arrays

I have a tensor array of arrays and an array of indices. I want to choose the corresponding elements from the arrays according to the indices given.
For e.g. If my array of arrays is : `[[1,1],[3,1],[4,5],[7,2],[6,0]]`
and my array of indices is `[0,0,1,1,0]` then I want my output to be `[[1],[3],[5],[2],[6]]`.
How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Like I said, my array was a torch.tensor array and not a regular array, so I didnt really find an answer to my exact question. As for coding, this problem did appear in my code which consists of a lot of other stuff and this was one of the errors that was stoppiing me from moving forwards, so it's not like I'm only writing a code to extract elements from tensors. I apologize if this question appeared under-reserached. This was one of the many error I was getting and the only one to which I was not finding a solution so I asked it on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this using `zip`

```
lst = [[1,1],[3,1],[4,5],[7,2],[6,0]]
ind = [0,0,1,1,0]

[[l[i]] for l,i in zip(lst, ind)]

[[1], [3], [5], [2], [6]]
```

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that my arrays were not nd.arrays but instead torch.tensors. But I found a way to do that as well using .gather() function.